# Combining width and max-width

Tags: css

Say I have this:

```css
.box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

From playing around with this, it looks like the box will take up 80% of the parent container as long as it will not expand beyond 600px. Once the parent stretches further, the box will remain fixed in width and not take up 80% of the page. Right?

Comment: ehm... yeah, thats right^^

Answer (score 2):

```
 .box {
     width: 600px;
     height: 300px;
     background: green;
     max-width: 80%;
  }
```

Let's break it down:

Te box's `width` is defaulted at 600px, this means that the div will always have a width of **600px**

Your `max-width` property restricts the width however, if the total space of your parent element becomes smaller then **750px** (because 80% of 750 is 600). This means that the maximum width of the element will always be 80% of it's parent.

Example:

a 800px parent has enough space left when the width is 600px, so the width will be 600px

a 500px parent will not have enough space left when the width is 600px, so it will revert to 80% of the parent, and your div will be 400px

As for your question:

> Once the parent stretches further, the box will remain fixed in width and not take up 80% of the page. Right?

This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the 'box' will only use the 'max-width' property when it is in a situation where it is LESS than 600px wide.

Anything above and it will maintain its 600px width.